# How to make CompositeStateTrigger work with AdaptiveTrigger and DeviceFamilyStateTrigger UWP

Tags: xaml, triggers, uwp, uwp-xaml, visualstatemanager

I am trying to make `AdaptiveTrigger` and `DeviceFamilyStateTrigger` work with `CompositeStateTrigger`.

Found this [useful link](https://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.my/2016/02/an-adaptivetrigger-that-works-with.html) which guided me but still unable to make it to work

I've created a sample project at GitHub to reproduce [my issue here](https://github.com/Monsok/App2).

For reference, here's my XAML. What am I missing?

```
<Grid Background="AliceBlue" x:Name="gridRoot">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup >
            <VisualState x:Name="narrow">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                        <mytrigger:AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" MaxWindowHeight="520" />
                        <triggers:DeviceFamilyStateTrigger DeviceFamily="Desktop" />
                    </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="textBlock.Text" Value="Desktop is narrow" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="medium">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                        <mytrigger:AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="521" MaxWindowHeight="1199" />
                        <triggers:DeviceFamilyStateTrigger DeviceFamily="Desktop" />
                    </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="textBlock.Text" Value="Desktop is medium width" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                        <mytrigger:AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1200"/>
                        <triggers:DeviceFamilyStateTrigger DeviceFamily="Desktop" />
                    </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="textBlock.Text" Value="Desktop is wide" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid x:Name="gridText">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" FontSize="40" Text="My Text Block" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost right. The problem here is that you've set wrong property in your `AdaptiveTrigger`. In the `AdaptiveTrigger`, we should set `MinWindowWidth` and **MaxWindowWidth** but not `MaxWindowHeight`.

So you can change you code like following and it should be able to work.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="narrow">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                    <mytrigger:AdaptiveTrigger MaxWindowWidth="520" MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    <triggers:DeviceFamilyStateTrigger DeviceFamily="Desktop" />
                </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="textBlock.Text" Value="Desktop is narrow" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="medium">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                    <mytrigger:AdaptiveTrigger MaxWindowWidth="1199" MinWindowWidth="521" />
                    <triggers:DeviceFamilyStateTrigger DeviceFamily="Desktop" />
                </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="textBlock.Text" Value="Desktop is medium width" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="wide">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <triggers:CompositeStateTrigger Operator="And">
                    <mytrigger:AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1200" />
                    <triggers:DeviceFamilyStateTrigger DeviceFamily="Desktop" />
                </triggers:CompositeStateTrigger>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="textBlock.Text" Value="Desktop is wide" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```